# Made a complicated form, messed up structuring the submitted params hash and I can't fix it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This occurs when I try and submit some quiz answers:
[image]

I'm pretty new to rails, I've been at this for a while but I don't know what I missed. I THINK it's just the way I set up my form because if I just try and save the name of the survey it works fine. 
surveys/show.html.erb (I use @survey to grab survey data such as questions and answers).

```
<%= form_for(:submitted_survey, url: submitted_surveys_path) do |f| %>

<%= f.hidden_field :name, value: @survey.name %>

<%= f.fields_for :submitted_questions do |ff| %>

<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<ul> 

<%= ff.hidden_field :content, value: question.content %>
<%= ff.label question.content %>

<%= ff.fields_for :submitted_answers do |fff| %>

<% question.answers.each do |answer| %>

<%= fff.hidden_field :content, value: answer.content %>

<%= fff.label answer.content %>

<%= ff.radio_button(:user_answer, answer.content) %>


<% end #questions.answers.each do %>
<% end #fields_for answers %>

<%= ff.hidden_field :question_explanation, value: question.question_explanation %> 

</ul>

<% end #@questions.each do %>

<% end #fields_for questions %> 

<%= f.submit %>
<% end #form_for%>
```

In my surveys controller:

```
  def show
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    @questions = @survey.questions
    @submitted_survey = current_user.submitted_surveys.build if logged_in?

  end
```

user.rb:

```
has_many :submitted_surveys, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :submitted_questions, through: :submitted_surveys
has_many :submitted_answers, through: :submitted_questions
accepts_nested_attributes_for :submitted_surveys, :reject_if => -> (a) {a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

My models and associations:

```
class SubmittedSurvey < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
     has_many :submitted_questions, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :submitted_questions, :reject_if => -> (a) {a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class SubmittedQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :submitted_survey
     has_many :submitted_answers, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :submitted_answers, :reject_if => -> (a) {a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class SubmittedAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :submitted_question
end
```

Comment: Step 1 for this sort of question would be to look at the parameter hash. Also try removing things from your form so as to get the smallest possible example that reproduces the error.

Comment: Man I honestly have no idea... it seems like if I just try and submit `<%= f.hidden_field :name, value: @survey.name %>` in my form then it submits correctly but doing anything else breaks it completely. I'm so frustrated right now because I've been at this thing for DAYS and I'm just not getting it.